# Problema con punteros y printf

Tags: c

Me marca el siguiente error en la parte que muestro el legajo encontrado (en caso de que se encuente)

```
`apnom' has not been declared
```

No entiendo si me lo dice porque estoy cometiendo algun error en la funcion

```
struct alumnos * buscaleg (struct alumnos [ ], int *, int);
```

Muchas gracias

```
struct fecha
{ 
   int dia;
   int mes; 
   int anio;
};

struct alumnos
{
   int legajo;
   char apnom [35];
   char direc [40];
   struct fecha fe [2];  /* fecha nacimiento y fecha ingreso institución */
   int edad;
 };

 void carga_alu (struct alumnos [ ], int *); 
 struct alumnos * ordenaap (struct alumnos [ ], int);
 struct alumnos * buscaleg (struct alumnos [ ], int *, int);
 int main() 
 {

 struct alumnos alum[100];
 struct alumnos *punt;
 int cantalum=0, leging;
 struct alumnos *puntbusc;

 carga_alu(alum,&cantalum); 

 punt=ordenaap (alum,cantalum);
 printf("Arreglo ordenado: \n");
 for (int i=0; i<=cantalum-1;i++)
 { printf("El nombre del alumno es: %s \n", punt[i].apnom);
   printf("El legajo del alumno es: %d \n", punt[i].legajo);
   printf("La direccion del alumno es: %s \n", punt[i].direc);
   printf("La fecha de nacimiento del alumno es %d/%d/%d   \n",punt[i].fe[0].dia,punt[i].fe[0].dia,punt[i].fe[0].dia);
   printf("La fecha de ingreso del alumno es %d/%d/%d \n",punt[i].fe[1].dia,punt[i].fe[1].dia,punt[i].fe[1].dia);
   printf ("La edad del alumno es: %d \n", punt[i].edad); }

  printf("Ingrese el legajo del alumno a buscar");
  scanf ("%d", &leging);
  puntbusc=buscaleg(punt,&leging,cantalum);
  if (puntbusc==00000)
  { printf("El legajo no existe"); }
  else {printf("El nombre del alumno es: %s \n", puntbusc.apnom);
     printf("El legajo del alumno es: %d \n", puntbusc.legajo);
     printf("La direccion del alumno es: %s \n", puntbusc.direc);
     printf("La fecha de nacimiento del alumno es %d/%d/%d   \n",puntbusc.fe[0].dia,puntbusc.fe[0].dia,puntbusc.fe[0].dia);
     printf("La fecha de ingreso del alumno es %d/%d/%d \n",puntbusc.fe[1].dia,puntbusc.fe[1].dia,puntbusc.fe[1].dia);
     printf ("La edad del alumno es: %d \n", puntbusc.edad);}  




   system("PAUSE");
   return 0; 
   }


   void carga_alu (struct alumnos a[ ], int *c)
   {
   char rta='s';
   int i=0;
   while (rta=='s')
   { printf("Ingrese el nombre y apellido del alumno \n");
     gets(a[i].apnom);
     printf("Ingrese el legajo del alumno \n");
     scanf("%d",&a[i].legajo);
     while(getchar()!='\n');
     printf("Ingrese la direccion del alumno \n");
     gets(a[i].direc);
     printf("Ingrese la fecha de nacimiento del alumno: DIA \n");
     scanf("%d", &a[i].fe[0].dia); /*En fe[] pongo 0 porq la primer posicion   la uso para la fecha de nac*/
     while(getchar()!='\n');
     printf("Ingrese la fecha de nacimiento del alumno: MES \n");
     scanf("%d", &a[i].fe[0].mes);
     while(getchar()!='\n');
     printf("Ingrese la fecha de nacimiento del alumno: ANIO \n");
     scanf("%d", &a[i].fe[0].anio);
     while(getchar()!='\n');
     printf("Ingrese la fecha de ingreso a la institucion del alumno: DIA  \n");
     scanf("%d", &a[i].fe[1].dia);/*En fe[1] pongo 1 porque la segunda  posicion la uso para la fecha de ingreso*/
     while(getchar()!='\n');
     printf("Ingrese la fecha de ingreso a la institucion del alumno: MES  \n");
     scanf("%d", &a[i].fe[1].mes);
     while(getchar()!='\n');
     printf("Ingrese la fecha de ingreso a la institucion del alumno: ANIO \n");
     scanf("%d", &a[i].fe[1].anio);
     while(getchar()!='\n');
     printf("Ingrese la edad del aluno: \n");
     scanf ("%d", &a[i].edad);
     while(getchar()!='\n');
     *c=*c+1;
     i=i+1;
     printf("Desea cargar otro alumno? S o N \n");
     scanf("%c",&rta);
     while(getchar()!='\n');} }


     struct alumnos* ordenaap (struct alumnos a[], int ca) 
     {

     for(int i=0; i<=ca-1;i++)
     {  for (int m=0; m<=ca-2;m++)
       { if(a[m].apnom>a[m+1].apnom)
           {struct alumnos aux=a[m];
            a[m]=a[m+1];
            a[m+1]=aux;} } }

    return a; }


   struct alumnos * buscaleg (struct alumnos alumo[], int *li, int canta)
   {
   int bajo=0,alto=canta-1,centro;
   while (bajo<=alto)
   { centro=(bajo+alto)/2;
     if (*li=alumo[centro].legajo)
      { return &alumo[centro]; }
      else if (*li<alumo[centro].legajo)
             {alto=centro-1;}
      else {bajo=centro+1;} }

  alumo[canta].legajo=00000;
  return &alumo[centro]; }
```

Comment: La verdad que no entiendo ni que estas buscando..que pasa si no encuentras el alumno que estas buscando?

Comment: El problema que tienes no es ni de punteros ni de printf, es que no debes estar encontrando ningun registro que cumpla la condicion y por lo tanto el struct debe estar vacio

Comment: En la funcion buscar legajo, puse que si no lo encuentra al legajo le asigne 0 y luego en el main hago la comparacion , si legajo es igual a cero que muestre "No existe legajo" y en caso contrario mostrar los datos. @gbianchi

Comment: Pero me suena a que estoy teniendo un error en la parte de la funcion de busqueda, para mi esta mal como lo plantee. Pero no logro saber cual es el error. @gbianchi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes varios problemas en tu código, pero voy a comenzar por los fallos que entiendo se te está quejando el compilador.

Defines una variable puntbusc, puntero a la clase alumnos.

```
struct alumnos *puntbusc;
```

Sin embargo en los `printf` obvias que la variable es un puntero y utilizas un `.` en lugar de `->`:

```
 printf("El nombre del alumno es: %s \n", puntbusc.apnom);
```

Tienes que cambiarlo por:

```
 printf("El nombre del alumno es: %s \n", puntbusc->apnom);
```

Y así con todo el resto de sentencias printf:

```
 printf("El legajo del alumno es: %d \n", puntbusc->legajo);
 printf("La direccion del alumno es: %s \n", puntbusc->direc);
 printf("La fecha de nacimiento del alumno es %d/%d/%d   \n",puntbusc->fe[0].dia,puntbusc->fe[0].dia,puntbusc->fe[0].dia);
 printf("La fecha de ingreso del alumno es %d/%d/%d \n",puntbusc->fe[1].dia,puntbusc->fe[1].dia,puntbusc->fe[1].dia);
 printf ("La edad del alumno es: %d \n", puntbusc->edad);
```

De esta forma, el compilador dejará de quejarse de apnom.

**EDIT1**:

Por otro lado, tienes este if en la función buscaleg:

```
if (*li=alumo[centro].legajo)
```

Entiendo que lo que quieres es hacer una comparación (`==`) no una asignación (`=`) ¿no?

Comment: Muchisimas gracias. Ahora lo voy a cambiar.
Pero tengo una duda, porque si podes mira el codigo mas arriba donde muestro todo el arreglo de alumnos que tambien utilizo un puntero y lo hice de la siguiente forma: punt[i].legajo
y ahi me funciono perfecto, sera porque era un arreglo? o cual es la diferencia? te agradezco si me sacas esa duda. Muchas gracias

Comment: Eso es, cuando utilizas `[]` estas obteniendo un objeto del tipo del array al que accedes, es decir, si tienes un `int arr*`, la sentencia `arr[0]` devuelve el `int` que se encuentra en la primera posición del array.

Comment: Muchas Gracias!! si, queria hacer una comparacion, fue un error de tipeo, gracias por mencionarlo porque no lo habia notado. @davidisla